# Convert 1 AM PST to local time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, safari

We have a system script that runs everyday at 1 AM PST. We have users around the world. We want to provide a simple web page that uses JavaScript to show 1 AM PST in the user's local timezone. For instance, a user in New York City should see 4 AM PST as the time the system script will run.

The PST time format is HH:MM DD.YYYY.

This only needs to work on mobile Safari.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What format has your time exactly? Please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would something like this:

```
alert(new Date(your_pst_server_time).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: What would your_pst_server_time be here?

Comment: At what format do you have the your local PST time? Is is HH:MM DD.YYYY? Or an ISO format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.getUTCHours()` and `.getTimezoneOffset()` methods of the `new Date()` object. For the ease of use, I attached this new function to that object. It will accept a parameter that specifies the time format that gets returned.

```
Date.prototype.getLocalTime = function (format){
    var date = new Date();
        var finalTime = ((date.getUTCHours()-2))-(((date.getTimezoneOffset())/60));
    if (format+'' != '24'){
        if (finalTime < 0){ finalTime = finalTime + 24 }
    }
    else {
        if (finalTime > 12){ finalTime = (finalTime - 12)+" PM" }
        else { finalTime += " AM" }
    }
    return finalTime.toString();
}
```

With my CET timezone, calling `new Date().getLocalTime('24')` will return `"10"` and calling `new Date().getLocalTime()` *(without parameters or a parameter that isn't `"24"`)* will return `"10 AM"`.

[Time Conversion Site to check timezones](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=0,8,12&h=0&date=2013-2-24&sln=9-10)

Answer (score 0):

This function is a reasonable first start, but would not cope with countries like India which have a time offset of x.5 hours (x hours + 30mins).  Unfortunately you cannot just divide by 60 like that.